If the row reduced echelon form of a matrix has $k$ linearly independent rows, does the original matrix also have $k$ linearly independent rows?

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N},$ and let $A$ be a $m×n$ matrix. Let $A'$ be the row reduced echelon form of $A.$ We know that all the non-zero rows of $A'$ are linearly independent. Suppose there are $k$ of these. Does this mean that $A$ too has $k$ linearly independent rows?

The result holds true when $A$ is square and invertible. In that case, $A'=I_n$ and $I_n$ has $n$ linearly independent rows. The $n$ rows of $A,$ too, must be linearly independent. Else, one of the rows is a linear combination of the others and hence the determinant of $A$ would be $0.$
From the examples we talked about in class, the same seems to hold for any matrix in general. I'm convinced that applying row operations to a matrix doesn't change the row space, but I don't see why the number of linearly independent rows must be the same.
In a similar vein, one can prove that the columns of $A$ corresponding to the linearly independent columns of $A'$ are themselves linearly independent. This leads me to believe that the above property must be true for the rows (though it may not be the corresponding rows, since we may perform many row swaps and such to reach the row reduced echelon form).
How to prove this, if true?

The maximal number of linearly independent rows of a matrix $M$ is the dimension of the row space of $M$. And the number $k$ of non-zero rows of $A'$ that you have mentioned is the dimension of the row space. So, since the row operations don't change the row space, the maximal number of linearly independent rows of $A$ must be $k$ too.

Right. But in my class, we haven't done dimension yet. We haven't even proved that any two finite basis sets of a vector space (if they exist) must have the same number of elements. Is there any other way to see this?

Also, if I understand correctly, this shows that $A$ can have at most $k$ linearly independent rows. My question asks if $A$ always has exactly $k$ linearly independent rows. Note that I do not know if this claim is true.

Yes, the statement is true. Besides, at no point I wrote that $A$ can have at most $k$ linearly independent rows. What I wrote was that the largest number of elements of a linearly independent set of rows of $A$ is $k$, rather than smaller than or equal to $k$. So, there is a set of $k$ linearly independent rows of $A$.

Okay, yes. I had a feeling I was misunderstanding the wording. The word "maximal" confused me as I have not come across that in class yet. Is there any way to see this that doesn't involve dimension?

Right now, I don't see how to answer your question without reference to dimension.

I see. I ask if such a solution exists since the analogous statement for columns and column space follows easily. But I believe that's just because of how matrix multiplication is defined. Thanks anyway!

I'm glad I could help.
